# How can I stop the Iframe from constantly reloading after setInterval (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just a novice with js

How can I keep the page from not constantly reloading after a setinterval?

Basically, it needs to check an external JSON file for a value of 0/1 and show and hide the Iframe src (it needs to keep checking the file every 5 seconds for changes), only reload if the value changes.

is there a way to story the value locally or cache it?

```
function ScreenSwitch(){
$.getJSON(screenNumberUrl, (data) => {
  if(data.ScreenState == 0){
    $("#os-iframe").attr("src", "about:blank");
  } else {
    $("#os-iframe").attr("src", "OverallStandings.html");
  }
});
}
ScreenSwitch();
setInterval(ScreenSwitch, 5000);
```

Comment: If you give it a class to signify if the iframe is about blank or not, then you chould check if that was set.  If it is set, and the ScreenState is still 0, don't do anything

Comment: I think this is a good start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Variable

Comment: so cancel the interval after it changes??? or if the value keeps changing, than store the value....

Comment: Thank you! for your solutions and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the logic to store the previously retrieved value. Then you will know if the value changes on the next request in order to update the `src` of the `iframe`. Try this:

```
function ScreenSwitch() {
  $.getJSON(screenNumberUrl, (data) => {
    if (previousScreenState != data.ScreenState) {
      $("#os-iframe").attr("src", data.ScreenState == 0 ? 'about:blank' : 'OverallStandings.html');
    }
    previousScreenState = data.ScreenState;
  });
}

var previousScreenState;
ScreenSwitch();
setInterval(ScreenSwitch, 5000);
```

The above logic is assuming that it's possible for `data.ScreenState` to dynamically change between `0` and `1` multiple times during runtime. If it's only possible for it to change once then this can be made simpler still.

Comment: Thank you.made some small changes and it worked.  function ScreenSwitch() {
    $.getJSON(screenNumberUrl, (data) => {
      previousScreenState == data.ScreenState;
      
      if (previousScreenState != data.ScreenState) {
        $("#os-iframe").attr("src", data.ScreenState == 0 ? 'about:blank' : 'OverallStandings.html');
      }
      previousScreenState = data.ScreenState;
    });
  }
  
 
  ScreenSwitch();
  setInterval(ScreenSwitch, 5000);

Comment: The `previousScreenState == data.ScreenState` line you added doesn't actually do anything, so I'm not sure what difference you believe it made.

Comment: I removed that line that was not the issue. it was a simple ); just before the previousScreenState that was blocking the script from running, once removed it works great.

Comment: Ahh yes, apologies. I should have tested it first :)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#os-iframe").attr("src"` will load the iframe. Why not

```
var url = "screenNumberUrl"+"&rnd="+Date.getTime(); // stop caching
$.get(url,function(data) { 
  if (data.ScreenState == 0) $("#someDiv").hide();
  else $("#someDiv").load("OverallStandings.html").show();

})
```

then you do not even need an iFrame

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan

made tiny changes and it works the way I want it. Thanks.

```
 function ScreenSwitch() {
  $.getJSON(screenNumberUrl, (data) => {

   if (previousScreenState != data.ScreenState) {
    $("#os-iframe").attr("src", data.ScreenState == 0 ? 'about:blank' : 'OverallStandings.html');
   }
   previousScreenState = data.ScreenState;
 });
}


ScreenSwitch();
setInterval(ScreenSwitch, 5000);
```